# How does one write an transformation matrix under an orthonormal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, orthonormal

I have an orthonormal basis (consisting of either vectors or polynomials). How do I write a matrix for a linear transformation $Tv=w$ for any vector $v$ and $w$ in the vector space $V$? Is there a general process for doing this?

For example, $T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(3x_1,2x_3,x_2)$ under orthonormal basis matrix
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}

would be written as:

\begin{pmatrix}3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 0\end{pmatrix}

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just apply the transformation to the basis vectors, express the images as column vectors, and put them together to form the matrix. 
so the correct matrix should be
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 0 
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: So `matrix M = span{T(''e1''),...,T(''en'')}`?

Answer (score 1):

For *any* basis, the columns of the transformation matrix are the images—expressed relative to that basis—of the basis vectors.